# MediaPlayer.Play(song) - can't be called twice with the same song?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xna, windows-phone-7

this is what i have:

> MediaPlayer.Play(DataFile.AllMusicTitles[0].SongFile);
>   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
>   MediaPlayer.Play(DataFile.AllMusicTitles[1].SongFile);
>   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
>   MediaPlayer.Play(DataFile.AllMusicTitles[0].SongFile);

play s0, sleep, play s1, sleep, then play s0, then 2nd time i play s0, doesn't work. i don't hear anything. is there something wrong w/ how .Play works?

i also tried stopping the song before each play but still doesn't help.

update: if the song to be played twice is from the Medialibrary it works! But if you create a song from an uri it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Naximus, Have you looked for anything that might help release resources that might not have been closed properly following the initial play? Or perhaps clear the currently playing song between each play to see if it helps? You could add XNA tag to your question too, being an xna library.

Comment: How are you creating the song from a uri?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reset the current position of S0 before you replay it? I believe there is a Seek method. If so, try passing in 0 (to set it to the beginning of the song).

Answer (score 0):

Like you said SongFromUri is not working right (if someone know why, please tell). If you want use users music, use MediaLibrary. If you want play some music of your project, use Content.Load("mysong").